# getStaticPaths was added without a getStaticProps - typescript

Tags: typescript, next.js, sanity

I am creating a blog using nextJS, typescript and sanity CMS. I have created the homepage where the post shows perfectly. next I am fetching the blog post details when I click the post with their individual slug. This query fetch data perfectly when I call it inside sanity dashboard here

[image: This query fetch data perfectly when I call it inside sanity dashboard here:]

**this is Post typings**

```
export interface Post {
  _id: string
  _createdAt: string
  title: string
  author: {
    name: string
    image: string
  }
  description: string
  mainImage: {
    asset: {
      url: string
    }
  }
  slug: {
    current: string
  }
  body: [object]
}
```

**[slug].tsx:**

```
import { GetStaticProps } from 'next'
import Header from '../../components/Header'
import { sanityClient, urlFor } from '../../sanity'
import { Post } from '../../typings'

interface Props {
  post: Post
}
function Post({ post }: Props) {
  //   console.log(post)
  return (
    <main>
      <Header />
      {/* <img src={urlFor(post.mainImage).url()} alt="" /> */}
    </main>
  )
}

export default Post
```

```
export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const query = `*[_type == "post"]{
        _id,
        slug{
            current
        }
    }`
  const posts = await sanityClient.fetch(query)
  const paths = posts.map((post: Post) => ({
    params: {
      slug: post.slug.current,
    },
  }))

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: 'blocking',
  }
}
```

```
export const GetStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const query = `*[_type == "post" && slug.current == $slug][0]{
  _id,
  _createdAt,
  title,
  author-> {
  name,
  image
},
 description,
 mainImage,
 slug,
 body
}`
  const post = await sanityClient.fetch(query, {
    slug: params?.slug,
  })

  if (!post) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }
  return {
    props: {
      post,
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  }
}
```

**The error I am getting is:**

```
Error: getStaticPaths was added without a getStaticProps in /post/[slug]. 
Without getStaticProps, getStaticPaths does nothing
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is you defined `getStaticProps` wrongly. If you notice that your definition is `GetStaticProps` (the first letter is capitalized) which is not `getStaticProps` (the function of Next.js' life cycle)

For the fix, you just need to modify it to `getStaticProps: GetStaticProps`

```
export const getStaticProps: GetStaticProps = async ({ params }) => {
  const query = `*[_type == "post" && slug.current == $slug][0]{
  _id,
  _createdAt,
  title,
  author-> {
  name,
  image
},
 description,
 mainImage,
 slug,
 body
}`
  const post = await sanityClient.fetch(query, {
    slug: params?.slug,
  })

  if (!post) {
    return {
      notFound: true,
    }
  }
  return {
    props: {
      post,
    },
    revalidate: 60,
  }
}
```